# Front End Find feature broken in Version 10 with OSX Mavericks?

Tags: front-end, mac-os-x, version-10

I installed Mathematica 10 and on my Macbook-Pro with OSX Mavricks. I was most frustrated to find that the front-end Find feature doesn't work. Do others have this problem? Is it possible something got messed up during download & installation?

Comment: I tried very basic things upon reading this and it worked. I have the same setup. If you have any particular examples where it doesn't work it would be a good idea to include them.

Comment: Working with me. windows 8.1

Comment: it seems to work fine here (OS X 10.9.4, mma 10.0)

Comment: Works here, OS X 10.9.4.  Can you try to reset some Front End settings by holding down Shift-Command during startup?

Comment: @Szabolcs, problem is solved after holding down Sift-Command during startup. Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some front end troubles can be solved as described here:

- [Troubleshooting](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TroubleshootingTheWolframSystem.html)

On OS X holding down Shift-Command during startup will reset the caches.  This is worth trying when the front end is misbehaving.

---

When having multiple versions of Mathematica installed, some problems can be avoided by using separate configurations for the different front end versions.  This can be set on the System tab of the Preferences window.